# How to Identify two or three pattern in a string and delete all the elements from the first identification to last?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

My test text `u = '    Danish  Phone is the work number Contact Type'`.

The regex pattern i used to identify three words `(Phone|Contact|Type)`.

This is perfectly identifying the words, Now I want to replace all the words from **Phone** to **type** with blanks.

So my final string output will be `Danish`.

Can anyone solve using regex in most pythonic way?

Comment: asking to clarify: if the text was `Danish  Phone is the work number Contact Type some more random stuff Phone plus last words` would the desired output be `Danish plus last words`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re 
u = '    Danish  Phone is the work number Contact Type'
u = re.sub('Phone.*?Type', '', u).strip()
```

`.*` is to match all characters between `Phone` and `Type`.

The `?` is used for non-greedy searches.

> the non-greedy qualifiers *?, +?, ??, or {m,n}? [...] match as little text as possible.

For example:

```
u = '    Danish  Phone is Type the work number Contact Type'
```

With `?`, it gives: `Danish   the work number Contact Type`.

Without `?`, it gives: `Danish`.

Comment: Worth noting is that to get `'Danish'` instead of `'    Danish  '` you'll also need to do `u.strip()` afterwards.